# Export/import Solr collection

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

I am trying to export datas from a collection and import to another but it's not really working. There are 2 different Solr instances and they can't be plugged, so I have to do it manually.

Export

```
curl --negotiate -u : "http://server1.fr.intranet:8983/solr/collection_source/select?q=*:*&wt=json&indent=true&rows=10000" >> collection_source.json
```

Import

```
 curl --negotiate -u : "http://server2.fr.intranet:8983/solr/new_collection/update/json?commit=true" --data-binary @/home/toto/collection_source.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

collection_source.json has to be modified before import, removing first fields (added by Solr), otherwise you can't import your file. 
Then, there is a version issue. In each doc inside my json there is version field "*version*":12121 with a value that can change, depending I guess when the doc has been uploaded to Solr. Anyway, this is causing a "version conflict" issue. If I remove version field it works, but I loose doc hierarchy and all consistency.

So what is the best way and how to do it properly, exporting and importing a whole Solr collection ? Or what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [Making and restoring backups](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/making-and-restoring-backups.html)?

Comment: Yes and it doesn't work, because I have 4 nodes 4 replicas on source and only 2 nodes on destination, it raises an error. I tried to add "maxShardsPerNode=2" to my command but it fails with '"ADDREPLICA failed to create replica'